# Level-shifting for negative-voltage logic

Tags: level-shifting

I'm trying to fix a 1970-vintage calculator - a Wang 360 (http://www.oldcalculatormuseum.com/wang360.html) - for a hobby project.

The power supply voltages are +11V and -11V. It looks like a logic "0" is 0V and a logic "1" is -11V. I'd like to shift these levels to normal TTL/CMOS so I can hook up my logic analyzer and get down to tracing the faults.

I've thought of several things, none of which are entirely satisfactory and I'm wondering if there's something better out there. I'll need to monitor as many as 16-lines so parts count per level shifter is an issue. Here's what I've thought of:

- A simple transistor circuit. Pro: easy & cheap. Con: high parts count (probably 3-4 resistors per shifter).
- An inverting op-amp with "gain" of ~3/11 to convert -11 to +3V. Pro: easy and relatively cheap. Con: moderate parts count (2-3 resistors per channel: Rin, Rfeedback, and an optional pull-down resistor).
- An opto-isolator. Pro: low parts count (2 resistors for current limiting; one on input & the other on output). Con: too high current drain. Typical ones draw 20mA! "low current" ones draw 0.5mA - at 11V, that's ~equivalent to ~22K and the resistors in the circuits are often larger than that. There are very expensive ones that draw 10's of uA but they cost $5 each.
- A "digital isolator" - Pro: low parts count. Con: expensive and require ~20mA input current.
- a comparator. Here, I think I'd need one that can have separate power supplies for the input (+/-11V) and output (5V). There are some like this (LM361 & AD790) but they're very expensive (at least $5 each). As far as I know,  "regular" comparator would have to be run from -11V and either 0V or +11V so the output would swing from -11 to +11 and that's not good.

So, it's looking like the op-amp is the best choice. But am I missing something?

Any help/suggestions/thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you feed the computer and the logic analyzer with two isolated power supplies, and then hook the GND of the logic to -11V, the inputs to the logic will be 0V for logic 0 and +11V for logic one. Then with resistor dividers for each signal you can limit the inputs to whatever range you want, 0-5, 0-3.3, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Claudio. In typical fashion, an hour after I posted my question, I came up with a possible answer. I could use a CMOS switch like a 4066 - they have a very large allowable power supply voltage. If you set their Vss to -11V and Vdd to +5V, their logic input will close the output switch when the signal goes above about -8.5V. If you connect the input of the switch to +5V and the output to a pull-down resistor to ground, it should work. Your solution is simpler but I'd have to be very careful not to let the two different grounds come into contact. Thanks again.

Comment: Another option might be to use something like the ULN2001A (Darlington array, open-collector outputs). It can also handle high voltages, but you may run into trouble if you place GND at -11V.